# Which usage is correct when re-initialising a numpy array?

Tags: python

I need to re-initialise an array to zero inside my program.  What is better style/ correct: reuse a np.zeros statement or set the array items to zero using a for statement?

Method A

```
    a=np.zeros((m,n))
    ...
    for ne in range(nel):
        ...
        a=np.zeros((m,n))
```

Method B

```
    a=np.zeros((m,n))
    ...
    for ne in range(nel):
        ...
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                a[i,j]=0.
```

Comment: Can you provide code snippets for 2 solutions you are entertaining?

Comment: it simpler and more readable to use again `np.zeros((m,n))` but you can use directly `a[:] = 0` to set zero to all values

Answer (score 1):

It simpler and more readable to use again

```
a = np.zeros((m,n))
```

but the simplest is to assign all values at once

```
a[:] = 0
```